# I'm trying to find a book about alien clanships

Tags: story-identification, aliens

The book began with a human male accidentally being sold as a slave to a clanship of aliens.  The aliens were much bigger and stronger than the human so ended up protecting him from their own kind. The human eventually was adopted by the clan. I believe it developed into a series and I read it more than 25 years ago.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds closer to the Chanur series, honestly, or at least a mix of Chanur and Foreigner!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could it be [Foreigner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreigner_universe) by C. J. Cherryh? It seems to tick quite a lot of the boxes with aliens being substantially larger than humans, using slavery and operating in clans.

[image: Foreigner]

Comment: YESYESYES. You rock, I've been wracking my brain for days. Thank You so much. Off to search where I can read it online.

Comment: @brknthelaw - That's very naughty. I'm sure you'll face a **torrent** of abuse if you try that sort of thing.

Comment: Yeah, cuz it isn't on Scribd. pooh bear. roger wilco, will do.

Comment: Um, since I don't have 15 "reputation" I can't upvote. Can somebody upvote this for me? Please?